# Ошибка при TransitionAnimation -"Shared element must not be null"

Tags: android, activity, android-animation

**Ошибка:**

```
Process: pc.dd.fragment_animation, PID: 22407  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Shared element must not be null ...at pc.dd.fragment_animation.MainClass$1.onClick(MainClass.java:91)
```

Xml главной активити:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="pc.dd.fragment_animation.MainClass">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:transitionName="source2"
        android:id="@+id/source"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/image1"
        android:scaleType="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Код 2 активити на которую мы переходим после анимации:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/image_target"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:transitionName="tar"
    android:src="@drawable/image1"
    android:scaleType="center" />
```

Код onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_class);
final View photo = findViewById (R.id.image_target);
    final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.source);

image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainClass.this,   Second_Activity.class);
            intent.setAction(intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.putExtra(MainClass.this.EXTRA_PHOTO, R.drawable.image1);
            //String transitionName = (String) findViewById(R.id.image_target);
            startActivity(intent,
                    ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
                            MainClass.this,
                            photo
                            ,
                            "tar"
                    ).toBundle());
        }
    });
```

***Что не так, не могу понять?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в разметке главной активити отсутствует элемент image_target, а вы пытаетесь найти его и передать в анимацию перехода. Если элемент source должен превратиться в новой активити в image_target, то вам следует его и передавать в анимацию. Да и мне кажется переход заработает если просто для главной активити поменять `android:transitionName="source2"` на `android:transitionName="tar"` и код генерирующий ActivityOptions.

Comment: так я должен же передавать в функцию `makeSceneTransitionAnimation` изображение которое находиться не на главной автивити а изображение с той активити на которую я потом перейду, не так ли?

Comment: Не так, вы должны передать туда элементы которые должны анимировано переехать в новую активити из старой. Кроме того пока новая активити не создастся вы её элементы никаким образом и не получите. `findViewById` ищет элементы на текущей активити. Ну и если в старой и новой разметке элементы имеют одинаковые значения в атрибуте `android:transitionName`, то они вроде должны автоматически подхватываться анимацией перехода. Но в этом не уверен я с этими анимациями пока на практике вообще не работал.